# How to get the character width and height in the linux console using C++?

Tags: c++, linux, console, font-size, ioctl

I wrote a C++ tool to display a low-resolution preview of an image in the console using block characters and 4-bit coloring.
For displaying the image in the correct aspect ratio I need to figure out the width and height of the monospace font character in the console.

So far I have this solution:

```c
#if defined(_WIN32)
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define VC_EXTRALEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#elif defined(__linux__)
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#endif // Windows/Linux

void get_console_font_size(int& width, int& height) {
#if defined(_WIN32)
    static const HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFO cfi;
    GetCurrentConsoleFont(handle, false, &cfi);
    width = (int)(cfi.dwFontSize.X);
    height = (int)(cfi.dwFontSize.Y);
#elif defined(__linux__)
    struct winsize w;
    ioctl(fileno(stdout), TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
    width = (int)(w.ws_xpixel/w.ws_col); // error: w.ws_xpixel always is 0
    height = (int)(w.ws_ypixel/w.ws_row); // error: w.ws_ypixel always is 0
#endif // Windows/Linux
}
```

It works fine for Windows, but for Linux this returns `width=0` and `height=0` because `w.ws_xpixel` and `w.ws_ypixel` both are `0`. `w.ws_col` and `w.ws_row` work corectly though. Various posts on the internet say that the `ioctl` command is broken and doen't set `w.ws_xpixel`/`w.ws_ypixel`.

How to get the character width and height in Linux with `ioctl` or something else?

`ncurses` is not really an option because the header file is not available in the C++ standard headers.

[image]

Comment: You could first try it with ncurses. If you find a way you can check if you find a way to remove ncurses.